# Сравнение даты с датой из базы данных (PHP)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Код на php, делаю бота на callback для вк

Дело в том, что я выдаю мут какому то пользователю, допустим на 5 минут, и в БД я даю полю **mute_time** интервал `NOW() $mute Minute, mute = 1` **(mute 1, надо для того, чтобы была проверка, что если это число равняется 1, то пользователь получает предупреждения).**

Как мне сделать проверку на то, что если 5 минут прошло, то значение поля **mute** было равным **0**?

Comment: Крон задание. Но как вариант убрать вообще это значение и работать только с mute_time

Comment: Пожалуй мне нужно и то и то)

Comment: Есть способ кроме крона? Как то мне он не поможет...

Comment: Почему не поможет? Он будет проверять даты и выставлять мут на 0 у кого дата кончилась. Причем одним запросом в БД. Другое дело что надо ставить его еже минутно, что такое себе. Как вараиет муты вынести в отдельную таблицу и уже по ней крон гонять. 
Другой вариант: при каждом запросе скрипта проверять закончился ли mute_time  у текущего пользователя  и обновлять мут на 0, если он закончился.

Comment: Ну я понимаю это, но вот проблема, на сайте нет ssh консоли)

Comment: Ну обычно такие вещи бывают в панели, которая выдается хостингом. Или у вас совсем дно хостер, что ни ssh ни панели, где есть крон.

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, что дно)